# Counting growing tree trajectories

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I am looking for help:

Beginning with a single node ($\circ$), at each discrete time step I can add a node/link pair to any node currently in the tree. Nodes are unlabelled and the tree is undirected. This will produce a "tree trajectory", like this: 
$$
\circ \quad \rightarrow\quad   \circ - \circ \quad \rightarrow\quad \begin{array}{c} \ \ \ \ \circ - \circ \\ | \\ \circ \end{array} \quad \rightarrow\quad  \begin{array}{c} \ \ \ \ \circ - \circ \\ | \\\ \ \ \  \circ - \circ \end{array}
$$
Another tree trajectory might look like this: 
$$
\circ \quad \rightarrow\quad   \circ - \circ \quad \rightarrow\quad \begin{array}{c} \ \ \ \ \circ - \circ \\ | \\ \circ \end{array} \quad \rightarrow\quad  \begin{array}{c} \circ - \circ \\ | \ \  \backslash \\  \circ \ \ \  \circ \end{array}
$$

My questions are as follows:

1) How  many possible distinct (non-isomporhic) graphs are there with N nodes and N-1 edges?

It's easy to find this by brute force up to 5: 
N=1: 1; N=2:1; N=3:1; N=4:2; N=5:3

2) For N nodes, how many different tree trajectories are there connecting the graph with N=1 node to the any graph of N nodes? (i.e., how many distinct tree trajectories are there; a tree trajectory is distinct from all others if for any other tree trajectory, there is at least a single step where the two are not isomorphic.) It's clear not just multiplying the number of non-ismorphic graphs at each step, since past graph topology will constrain future graph topologies.

While a solution would obviously be great, ANY help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer to your first question is in OEIS.  See here: https://oeis.org/A000055

Comment: This was helpful - I should have thought to search unlabeled. Still thinking about question two...

Comment: A note: This is similar to counting number of Young diagrams of some size, and a trajectory of Young diagrams is just a standard Young tableau....

You can probably encode a trajectory as a linear extension of some poset.

Answer (score 2):

The total number of trajectories $T(N)$ (as a function of $N$) appears to be

```
N   T(N)
1   1
2   1 
3   1 
4   2 
5   4 
6   13 
7   48 
8   235 
9   1297 
10  8628 
11  63902 
12  538454 
13  4973090 
14  50621738 
15  557399709 
16  6636723151
17  84584674076
18  1151419603932
19  16640050320703
20  254656634876886
21  4110614617328251
```

I've added these counts to the OEIS as [sequence A268951](https://oeis.org/A268951).

Comment: The question is rather ambiguous (isomorphism must be defined more precisely), and your answer does not fit the first few terms given.

Comment: @F.C.: I defined it precisely in the OEIS. What given terms do you refer to? I see only terms given for question 1), but nothing for question 2). My counts are about question 2).